# How to initialize var when it is used for different things in a method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, var

I have a method in my controller that is performing some logic based on data submitted and my `var`item should be assigned to different results?

For example my controller's method is something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(SearchCriteria criteria)
{
    var db = new EbuyDataEntities();

    //criteria.SearchKeyword = "movie";
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(criteria.SearchKeyword))
    {
       var auctionData = db.Auctions.First(q => q.Description.Contains(criteria.SearchKeyword));
    }
    else
    {
        var auctionData = db.Auctions.OrderBy(item => item.EndTime);
    }

    switch (criteria.GetSortByField())
    {
        case SearchCriteria.SearchFieldType.Price:
            auctionData = auctionData.OrderBy(q => q.CurrentPrice.Value);
            break;
        case SearchCriteria.SearchFieldType.RemainingTime:
            auctionData = auctionData.OrderBy(q => q.EndTime);
            break;
        case SearchCriteria.SearchFieldType.Keyword:
        default:
            auctionData = auctionData.OrderBy(q => q.Title);
            break;
    }

    auctionData = SomeMethod();
    var viewModel = new SearchViewModel();

    return View("Search",viewModel);
}
```

What is the right way to do something like this.

Comment: Using `var` tells the compiler "figure out what the type of this is yourself," it does not mean "the type of this will change and/or might be different in different execution paths." So (ignoring issues of scope) your conditional will *never* work, because one call returns a single object and the other returns an `IEnumerable` - those two things are different types and can't be assigned to the same variable in this way (unless, as Jon suggests in his answer, you meant to use `Where` instead of `First`).

Comment: For more information on the `var` keyword: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, two options:

- Move the declaration to before the `if` statement, and give it an explicit type:

  ```
  IQueryable<Auction> auctionData;
  if (...)
  {
      ...
  }
  else
  {
      ...
  }
  ```
- Change the structure to only have a single declaration, e.g. using the conditional operator:

  ```
  var auctionData = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(criteria.SearchKeyword)
      ? db.Auctions.Where(q => q.Description.Contains(criteria.SearchKeyword))
      : db.Auctions.OrderBy(item => item.EndTime);
  ```

Note that I've changed `First` to `Where` here - otherwise you would only be matching a *single* entry, which doesn't sound like much of a search to me, and would make of the rest of the method very odd.

That in itself suggests a third option:

```
var auctionData = db.Auctions.OrderBy(item => item.EndTime);
var keyword = criteria.SearchKeyword;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword))
{
    auctionData = auctionData.Where((q => q.Description.Contains(keyword));
}
```

Comment: I'll note that, while not relevant in this particular case, if the type of the query was of an anonymous type it would change which of these options are viable.

Comment: Such as your second option.  Just not the first.

Comment: @Servy: Sorry, yes - a slightly modified form of the first - using `var`, but with a dummy value: `var auctionData = new [] { new { ... } }.AsQueryable();`